# Window 10 compatibility issues?

Tags: compatibility, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I made a new installation of Windows 10 pro on a drive that only had a new Windows 7 pro installation.

When I started installing softwares and drivers, I got several instances of “this software is not compatible with this version of Windows”.

My understanding was that the Windows pro version was backward compatible up to XP.

- Or do I need to roll back to Windows 7 first, then install the softwares I need, and then re-install Windows 10?

Yet, if I do that would I need to redo that every time I want to add other softwares not made for Windows 10?

EDIT:

> My understanding was that the Windows pro version was backward compatible up to XP.

i meant the virtual PC- XP simulator thing...

but if it is not compatible with win 7 products, i'll roll back to 7 as many softwares do not yet have a win 10 updated version

Comment: *"My understanding was that the Windows pro version was backward compatible up to XP."* Why would it be?

Comment: If an application is not Windows 10 compatible, it won't matter if you install it on Windows 7 and then upgrade to 10 or try to install it on 10, it won't work either way. The best thing to do is go through your software and hardware and check for compatibility before you upgrade. I think Microsoft has online compatibility checkers also.